# Android phone as offline router

Tags: wi-fi, networking

I currently use an old wireless router to connect two wifi devices.  The two devices connect to the SSID of the router, then the router allows traffic between them.  No internet connection/uplink is present.

Can I do the same with an android phone instead of the router?

I can't enable mobile hotspot since I'm not paying my carrier for this feature.  Paying the carrier might work but I shouldn't have to if I'm not using internet.

Also, mobile hotspot might block traffic between two devices on the mobile hotspot LAN, since the typical use case is to allow devices to contact internet but not necessarily each other.

Anyone figured how to do this?

HTC One M7, T-mobile 5.0 firmware, no root.

Comment: Hi! Questions asking us app suggestions/recommendations are off-topic here. Visit [help/on-topic] to know what's on-topic here. However, [softwarerecs.se] is the fitting place for such questions, provided that you follow their on-topic [guidelines](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Removed "is there an app.." from wording since I'm not necessarily looking for an app.  Anyways- I just found a duplicate question & flagged as such.

Comment: I have tried mobile hotspot on few devices previously, and the client devices can ping each other and talk to each other. FTP works too. But I haven't tried it on a carrier locked device.